# How do you change the cutoff parameter in R's randomForest?

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

The documentation says cutoff is "A vector of length equal to number of classes. The `winning' class for an observation is the one with the maximum ratio of proportion of votes to cutoff. Default is 1/k where k is the number of classes (i.e., majority vote wins)."

I want to implement a cutoff of probabilities of 0.6 or 0.7 not the default of 0.5.

```
RFfit <- randomForest(Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5, data=mydata, mytry=2, ntrees=500,
  cutoff = x)
```

I have tried various values for x. 0.6, 6, 12, 1.2... none seem to work. 
I have also added a column called "cutoff" to my data where all values are = 0.6, and tried calling that into the code, but that did not work either.

How do I use the cutoff argument properly?

Comment: According to help page `x` should have length equal to the number of classes. If you have two classes try to use `cutoff = c(0.6, 0.6)`. Did this help?

Comment: Tried that - didn't work!

Comment: `cutoff = c(0.6, 0.4)` is what you want.

Comment: Btw, your misspelled parameter `mytry=2` will be silently ignored. You meant `mtry=2`. Functions with passthrough args (`...`) can't tell whether args have been misspelled, they just silently ignore them.

Answer (score 7):

The correct format is

```
cutoff=c(k,1-k)
```

Where k can be any value between 0 and 1. For example,

```
cutoff=(0.7,1-0.7)
```

or

```
cutoff=(0.5,1-0.5)
```

Comment: what does `cutoff = c(0.7, 0.3)` mean from the RF view? so if 1000 trees were present and atmost 700 of them say `1` then predict `1` ?

Comment: @joel.wilson I have exactly the same question, although it is not direct to original question. Check this out https://gerardnico.com/data_mining/threshold for more info.